# Mixing MATCH AGAINST with JOINO in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is it possible to expand this query

```
SELECT id, name, MATCH (name) AGAINST (%s)
AS score FROM mydb.authors WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (%s)
```

by following one?

```
SELECT authors.id, papers.id FROM `mydb`.`auth2paper`
JOIN `mydb`.`papers` ON `mydb`.`auth2paper`.paper_id = `mydb`.`papers`.id
JOIN `mydb`.`authors` ON `mydb`.`auth2paper`.auth_id = `mydb`.`authors`.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why not.  Just use the MATCH in the WHERE as you normally would.

```
SELECT authors.id, papers.id, MATCH (`mydb`.`authors`.name) AGAINST (%s) Score
FROM `mydb`.`auth2paper`
JOIN `mydb`.`papers` ON `mydb`.`auth2paper`.paper_id = `mydb`.`papers`.id
JOIN `mydb`.`authors` ON `mydb`.`auth2paper`.auth_id = `mydb`.`authors`.id
WHERE MATCH (`mydb`.`authors`.name) AGAINST (%s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this wuery really the equivalent to the two queries obove? And how would you add the score? I need it further on in my code.

Comment: @aufwind - My apologies, you need it in the select clause indeed